# How to change datatype of field when it's dependent on procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, interbase

I'm running into issues where I cannot update the metadata of a table to change the datatype from VARCHAR(8) to VARCHAR(10). It says the column is referenced in procedures. There's a lot of those, I'm not going to drop them all just to edit the datatype and readd them. I don't understand why the proc would stop me from doing this, especially when i'm increasing size, not reducing.

I even had to delete triggers which reference it, because just setting them to inactive did not work.

Is there a work around for this?